# How to find the percentage of the final price?

Tags: php

I am developing an e-commerce app for my client and my client wants to show -20% like percentage to their customers, In other words I want to find the reverse of the final price and find out the percentage decrease value.

Here I displayed That How much amount can be saved.

```
<?php
$op = Original_price($detailedProduct->id);
$dp = Discounted_price($detailedProduct->id);

$ts = $op - $dp;
echo "You are saving $ts";
?>
```

[image]

In the screenshot above customer is saving 3% I also want to display -3%Off.
I know this is a simple math problem but I am stuck please help me out.

Comment: You need an extra -3% off to Orignal Price or discounted price???

Comment: @Mujahid Bhoraniya I just want to find the reverse value of the given percentage that how much percentage decrease is occured.

Comment: @Mujahid Bhoraniya Just like on this page https://www.banggood.com/12Pcs-2_0MM-2B-Lead-Holder-Mechanical-Pencil-with-12pcs-Refill-Set-Drafting-Drawing-Pencil-Refills-Set-Engineering-Pen-for-School-Art-Supplies-p-1333853.html?rmmds=flashdeals&cur_warehouse=CN

Comment: You can see my answer. If you need extra help you can go with my profile page and contact me via Linkedin, Whatsapp and Email as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula for calculating the discount percentage :

**Discount%=(Original Price - Discount Price)/Original Price*100**

Translating it into code, it should be something like :

```
$percent = (($op - $dp)*100) /$op ;
```

Comment: That's what I want to achieve thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: I am an E-commerce specialist. If you need help. you can contact me personally. because I am mostly not available on stack site.